# Create a Product Audience with Facebook Power Editor

Tags: facebook-ads-api

According to [Facebook Product Audience documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-audiences/#productaudience), one can create an audience to target people who, for example, have added a product to basket but not purchased it.

This can be done through `product_audiences` endpoint with:

```
inclusions=[{"retention_seconds": 86400,
  "rule": {"event": {"eq": "AddToCart"}}}]
exclusions=[{"retention_seconds": 172800,
  "rule": {"event": {"eq": "Purchase"}}}]
```

This also can be done directly within `adcampaigns` endpoint with ([see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/ads-management/#adset)):

```
"product_audience_specs": [{
  "product_set_id": <PRODUCT_SET_ID>,
  "inclusions": [..]
}]
```

**The problem is**: it seems that there is no way to create those Product Audiences with the [Power Editor](https://business.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor). The use of the API seems compulsory. Is it true?

*For info*: Power Editor can create [Custom Audience](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-targeting/v2.3), something like "target someone who've view product 1 and 2", but it's not as fine grained as Product Audience

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to do something via Facebook's Power Editor tool and not a programming question

Comment: I'm ok with this closing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is only available — for now on — in the api.
See here for the [related issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/964629233555291).